# Different Layout Managers in an Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-gridview, android-recyclerview

I have two different kinds of data that one of them needs to be displayed in a `GridLayout` (**Red**) and the other needs to be displayed `LinearLayout`(**Blue**).

The whole page scrolls and the data sources may change so the views should update dynamically.

How can I implement this in Android and probably with `RecyclerView`?
[image]

Comment: You would likely want to use Fragments to create a multi-layout Activity. Here's a good tutorial to get you started on multi-pane development: [http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to only use the GridLayoutManager with 2 Columns.
In case a listitem should wrap both columns set the columnspan for the item to 2 otherwise to 1.